# Android - save files to a folder visible in Windows Exploer phone USB mode

Tags: android, storage

I am trying to save a file to a path that will be visible in Windows Explorer when the phone is connected in USB mode.

```
  public static boolean sharedSetTextAsStrToDCIMStoragePath(Context ctx, String relative_dir, String file_name, String str, boolean mode_append)
  {
    File storage_files_dir_file = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    if (storage_files_dir_file.exists() == false) {
      return false;
    }
    sharedSetTextAsStrToCustomStoragePath(storage_files_dir_file, relative_dir, file_name, str, mode_append);
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ctx, new String[] {storage_files_dir_file.toString()}, null, null);
    return true;
  }
```

I have tried various paths - like downloads and dcim since those are visible in Windows explorer.

However, in Windows Explorer I can not see the files I have created even though I can see files are being created when stepping through the code.

Here's example addres in Windows Explorer:

*"This PC\HUAWEI P6-U06\Internal storage\DCIM\"*

The path I am getting when saving in Android is:

*"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.product.app/files/DCIM"*

Comment: Look for the Android directory first.

Comment: You have to look in __"This PC\HUAWEI P6-U06\Internal storage\Android\data\com.company.product.app/files/DCIM"__ and if you are trying to put the file in DCIM folder , you should try to write your file in *Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"DCIM/"*  ,hardcoded string should work as almost every android phone has a __/sdcard/DCIM__ folder

Comment: @Tom did you manage to solve the problem after two years?